# Need advice, Curtains, blinds, Shades? which to use, whats in currently?

Tags: blinds, curtain-rail

i need to purchase curtains/blinds or shades for all my windows in my apartment. I have 5 windows - 1 being a bathroom.

Its a small apartment and view outside the window isn't onto the main road but to other apartments..

What would you suggest?

I want a kind of modern look. I will have wooden laminate flooring. and i am thinking of painting the falls a neutral color like magnolia.

ANy ideas really appreciated.

Comment: Hanging blinds I'd qualify as home improvement ... and maybe selecting things based on function could have a good answer (eg, need to black out a room, or fit an odd opening) ... but style and trying to match the floor?  That's more home decorating and a bit too open ended.

Answer (score 1):

While this question may be ambiguous or style based I will try to give the best answer I can and let more qualified hands cast close votes.

I would recommend [sheers](http://everythinghomeandgarden.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/Sheer-Drapes.jpg). They allow plenty of light in, but obscure the inside of your apartment enough to allow some privacy. In terms or hardware, they are extremely easy to set up, if you have a recessed alcove window, just an expanding dowel rod is needed.  However if not, you will need brackets, this is also true for all blinds and curtains. I find curtains and blinds either bulky or they close out too much light when closed and offer no privacy when open.Sheers are the happy middle. If you want even more privacy then the link shows, a easy to add more is to double the sheer up. The obscuring feature of a  double sheer is compounded and yet still allows ambient light in while providing absolute privacy. However in the bathroom and bedroom, its possible you will still feel more comfortable with a thicker blind in which case a [underlying sheer with a solid curtain over](http://www.royalcarpetandcurtain.com/images/sheer%20curtains/shr5.jpg) it is best. To maximize the sheer, tie back the solid curtain during the day.

In terms of absolute style, which this site isn't about, the cream color of the magnolia and the  brilliant white of the sheers is seen in nearly every home in architectural digest or living magazine. Also white allows you to use varying colors in the room as white nearly goes with everything. All attempts at trying to use heavily colored sheers or drapes have come out looking Victorian and heavy. Plus choosing too bold a color as a big pieve of wall space sets you up for disaster. Depending on the wood color you could very well get away with a cream color sheer.

Comment: In addition: Curtains provide insulation if you live somewhere where it gets cold and your windows are not otherwise insulated (double glazed, shutters, ...). Also, curtains in a bathroom might get moldy quickly.